# creating table from SeqIO.parse python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I asked similar question to this one before, but the previous solution didn't solve my problem. I've been wondering around and testing things but nothing work properly.

I have a fasta file with more than 500 sequences, and from that file I need to build a table, so I am trying to write a script to do it instead of doing it by hand, with copy-paste.
I am reading the file using Biopython : `seq=SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta")`

From each sequence I want to know the specie the protein sequence belongs, the name of the protein and the Uniprot ID.  when I use the SeqIO to parse a fasta file I noticed that there is not much info I can parse from it.

Here is an subset of my fasta file:

```
>gi|194757291|ref|XP_001960898.1| GF11270 [Drosophila ananassae] >gi|190622196|gb|EDV37720.1| GF11270 [Drosophila ananassae] MSAARTSQDCDCTAKCRLRQHGNTITAALTKRSISSQNLAAFVYKTCGNFANILDDLGRSAVHMSASTGRYEILEWLLNH GAYINGQDYESGSSPLHRALYYGSIDCAVLLLRYGASMELLDEDTCCPLQAICRKCDVDDFATDSQNDVLVWGSNKNYNL GVGSEQNTNAPQSVDFFRKSNIWIEQVALGAYHSLFLDKKGHLYAVGHGKGGRLGTGGENTLPAPKRVKVSSKLGSEDSI RCISVSRQHSLVLTHRSLVFACGLNSDCQLGVRDAPEHLAQFKEVVALRDKGASDLVRVIACDQHSIAYGSRCVYVWGAN QGQFGISANIASIVVPTLIKLPARTTIRFVEANNAATVIYSEEKMIYLYYAEKTRAIKTPNYEDLKSISVMGGHIKNSAK GSAAALKLLMLTETNVVYLWYENTQQFYRCNFLPIRLPQIKKILYKCNQVMVLSEDGCVYRGKCNQIALPASELQEKSRP NLDIWQNNDQNRTEISREHVIRIELQRVPNIDRAVDISCDEGFSSFAVLQESQGKYFRKPTLPRKEHSFKKLLHDTSDCD AVHDVVFHVDGEKYPAHKYIIYSRAPGLRELVRMYLDKDIYLNFENLTGKMFELVLKHIYTNYWPTEDDIDCIQQSLGPA NPQNRSRTCQMFLPHLEKFQLTELAKYVKSYVQDHQFPLPSARQRLPRLHRSDYPELYDVKIKCEDGQVLQAHKCMLVAR LEYFEMMFMHSWAERSSVTMEGVPAEYMEPVLDYLYSLEAEAFCKQAYLETFLYNMITICDQYFIESLQNLCELLILDKI SIRKCGEMLEFATMYNCKLLLKGCMDFICQNLARVLCYRSIEQCDGETLKCLNDHYRNMFSRVFDYRQITPFSEAIEDEL LLSFIDGLEVDLEYRMDAESKAKQAAKTKQKDLRKLNARHQYEQRAISSMMRSISISESNPAPEVATSPQESARSETNNW SRVIDKKEQKRKQAETALKVNKTLKQETSPEPEMVPIERTPVNEQTPPPLSPETEPSTPLNKSYNLDFSSLTPQSQKLSQ KQRKRLSSESKSWRGNSSALLESPTTPVPVPNAWGVTTTPSSSFNDSYTSPTTGSSSDPTSFANMMRSQAASSSATSKDQ SQNFSKILADERRQRESYERMRNKSLVHTQIEETAIAELREFYNVDNIDDEKITIARKSRPSDINFSTWIRQ
>gi|198456847|ref|XP_001360463.2| GA20796 [Drosophila pseudoobscura pseudoobscura] >gi|198135774|gb|EAL25038.2| GA20796 [Drosophila pseudoobscura pseudoobscura] MSTAKAQEYDCTAKCTCRQHGNSITAALTKRSIDNQNLGAFIFKTCGNFANIIDDLGRSAVHMSASVARYEILEWLLNHG AYINGLDYESGSSPLHRALYYGSIDCAVLLLRYGASLELLDEDTRCPLQAICRKCDEDFTTESQNDVLVWGSNKNYNLGI GNEQNTNAPQAVDFFRKSNIWIEQVALGAYHSLFCDKKGHLYAVGHGKGGRLGIGVENSLPAPKRVKVSSKLNDDSIMCI SVSRQHSLLLTRRSLVFACGINTDHQLGVRDAPENLTQFREVVALRDKGASDLLRVIACDQHSIAYSTKCVYVWGANQGQ FGISRTTDTIMAPTLIKLPARTSIRFVEANNAATVIYTEEKMITLFYGDKTRYIKTPNYEDLKSIAVIGGHLKSSTKGSA AALKLLMLTETNVVFLWYENTQQFYRCNFSPIRLPEIKKILYKCNQVLILSLDGCVYRGKCNQIALPAGILEEKSKPNMD IWHNNDQNRTEISREHVIRIELQRVPNIDRATDIFCDESFSSFAVLQESHMKYFRKPPLPRREHNFKKLYHDTCESDAVH DVVFHVDGERFAAHKFILYSRAPGLRELTRIYLDKDVYLNFENLTGKMFELILKYIYTSYWPTEDDIDCIQESLGPANPR ERSRACEMFIPHLEMFQLVDLARYLQSYVRDNQFPIPSTRQRFNRLHRSDYPELYDVRIVCEDSKVLEAHKCMLVSRLEY FEMMFTHSWAERTTVNMEGVPAEYMEPVLDYLYSLDTEAFCKQNYTETFLYNMVTFCDQYFIESLQNVCESLILDKISIR KCGEMLDFAAMYNCKLLHKGCMDFICHNLARVLCYRSIEQCDEATLKCLNDHYRKMFSNVFDYRQITPFSEAIEDELLLS FVVDCDIDLDYRMDPETKLKAAAKHKQKDLRRQDARHYYEQQAISSMMRSLSVSESASGPEATTGPQESTRSEGKNWSRV VDKKEQKRKLADTALKVNNTLKLEEPPRPELEVIERALMKEQTPPPTSPAEETSTPLSKSYNLDLSSLTPQSQKLSQKQR KRLSSESKSWRSPLVEQEPTTPVAVPNAWGLPPATPSSSSFTDSPATGSISDPTSFANMMRGQAAAATTPTEKGQSFSRI LADERRQRESFERMRNKSLAHTQIEETAIAELREFYNVDNTDDETITIERKSRPTDINFSTWLKH
>gi|355695434|gb|AES00009.1| inhibitor of Bruton agammaglobulinemia tyrosine kinase [Mustela putorius furo] KPGNKLKLNQKKCSFLCDVTMKSVDGKEFTCHKCVLCARLEYFHSMLSSSWIEASTCTALEMPIHSDILKVILDYLYTDE AVVIKESQNVDFVCSVLVVADQLLITRLKGMCEVALTEKLTLKNAAMILEFAAMYNAEQLKLSCLQFIGLNM
```

Is there any way I get the Protein name, Uniprot ID and organism from those sequences? 
For example I thought on parsing the genebank id from the seq.description and then search in genebank with that ID but I think it cannot be made, not all the sequences have genebank ID.
Any suggestions how to do this? Any help would be really appreciated.

example of desired output:

```
name    organism    uniprot id  family
GF11270 Sophophora  B3MFN0  
GA20796 Sophophora  Q291S4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask biostar too : http://www.biostars.org/

Extract the ACN from your fasta header. eg: GF11270

and use the uniprot REST API to retrieve the record(s) associated to this ACN

http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=GF11270&sort=score&format=xml

http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=GF11270&sort=score&format=txt

http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=GF11270&sort=score&format=tab